# Mongo DB aggregation queries are not returning any data, while find queries does

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, match

I have a cart collection which contain userId's as a reference. I was trying to query them based on the userId. But I am getting an empty array for aggregation queries whiles using `$match` operator, whereas the find method is returning me the correct set of data.

```
const userCart = await CartModel.aggregate([{$match:{userId:userId}}])
console.log(userCart) 
const userCaet2 = await CartModel.find({userId:userId})
console.log(userCaet2)
```

Query result of aggregate pipeline userCart:

```
[]
```

Query result of find method userCart2:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('659c05531c2b885a7258cf66'),
    userId: new ObjectId('6596758ca603df575402189b'),
    __v: 0,
   items: [ [Object], [Object] ]
 }
```

]

The userCarts only has one doucment, its same as the query result of find method. cart schema:

```
const cartSchema = {
    userId:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "users",
        required:true,
        unique: true
    },
    items:[{
        productId:{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "products",
            required: true
        },
        quantity:{
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 1
        }
    }]
}

const CartModel = mongoose.model('userCarts',cartSchema)
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of your "CartModel"? the issue is there.

Comment: both ways work, see https://mongoplayground.net/p/sd5Wb3bCQEv, you should check your code

Comment: CartModel connects to the usercarts collection. Currently it has only one document and it looks like exactly as the query result of find method.